# Angularjs - Error: $location and $anchorScroll to scroll call 2 times to my controller

Tags: angularjs, anchor-scroll

I have some problems when using $anchorScroll for scrolling to element, can you help me?

This is my source:

ParentController:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
myApp.controller('ParentCtrl',function($scope){

}
```

ChildrenController:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
myApp.controller('ChildrenCtrl',function($scope,$location,$anchorScroll){
   $location.hash('tries');
   $anchorScroll();
   console.log('Hihi');      
}
```

Index.html

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
  <div ng-view> </div>
</div>
```

RESULT which i received:

```
HiHi

HiHi
```

I don't know, why is childrent controller call 2 times?

Help me, please!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have code that is instantiating your ChildrenCtrl, your html shows your ParentCtrl being called, but not the ChildrenCtrl.

Comment: In ParentCtrl, i use $location.path('/childrent') to forward view of ChildrenCtrl

Comment: Do you have a directive for ChildrenCtrl?

Comment: Yes, i have a directive for ChildrenCtrl...

Comment: Logically your directive is being instantiated twice (two element or attributes etc), most likey in your html.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the page reloads when you use `$location.hash` which updates the route, hence calling the controller again. Add `reloadOnSearch: false` to your route definitions to prevent page loading then.